# SQL string match is not exact

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search for all instances of an *exact* string on one column.

Both of the following lines return the same record sets.

```sql
select * from policy_templates where policy_content like '%[[Business Name]]%'
```

```sql
select * from policy_templates where policy_content like '%[[Business.Name]]%'
```

*(The difference is the period between Business and Name).*

---

None of the records actually contain `[[Business Name]]` - despite the query returning the same set of results. All instances are `[[Business.Name]]`.

---

I have ran a script to replace all instances of `[[Business Name]]` with `[[Business.Name]]`. This SQL ran as intended, and replaced all instances correctly. But, given the issue above, I would not be surprised if it were detecting `[Business.Name]]` and replacing it with `[[Business.Name]`, which is obviously unnecsary.

I've been testing this on a smaller data set of about 50 rows, before moving to a much, much larger set (in a production environment). The target column contains quite a lot of text, so I'd like to get this match to be exact to `[[Business.Name]]`, as it currently looks ambiguous to `[[Business Name]]`.

Comment: I would be surprised “if it were detecting”..

Comment: Also, this see if this returns the same (or similar) results: “%[[B]]%”

Comment: Could you please explain why that is the case? Why is it ignoring the `[[` and `]]`

Comment: running with `select * from policy_templates where policy_content like '%[[Business]]%'` returns the same set of rows. Something I'm not understanding here with the `%` character, perhaps? I've never seen this before.

Comment: See the LIKE syntax. [..] has special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'%[[]]%'` is used for regular expressions, and `.` means any character. as a result `'%[[Business Name]]%'` is equivalent to `[Business Name]` in Regex. [Here is](https://regexr.com/48n0e) small demonstration about the issue

Thus you need to escape `[` and `]` since they are special characters for `LIKE`

```
WHERE POLICY_CONTENT LIKE '%\[\[Business Name\]\]% ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Small note: `LIKE '%[[Business Name]]%'` checks for any character in '[Business Name' followed by ']'. (For example, the string `'e]'` would be returned for `LIKE '%[[Business Name]]%'`)

Comment: Thanks very much @Simonare. 

Using this, the results seem to be as expected now. 
I beleive you have a syntax error in your answer, it should read  `WHERE POLICY_CONTENT LIKE '%\[\[Business Name\]\]%' ESCAPE '\'`, correct?